# How to configure public port for an application deployed on CloudFoundry ?

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I've got a SpringBoot application running on port 8080 (default with Tomcat).

I'm deploying it to CloudFoundry Pivotal Platform with this command:

```
cf push my-project -p build/libs/myproject-0.1.0.jar
```

and this manifest.yml

```
---
applications:
- name: my-project
  memory: 1024M
  host: my-project
  port: 8080
```

This is from the log when the application is starting:

```
INFO 25 --- [ main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
INFO 25 --- [ main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService : Starting service Tomcat
INFO 25 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
```

The application is accessible from this url:

```
 http://my-project.cfapps.io/hello_world
```

But I need it to be accessible from port 8080:

```
 http://my-project.cfapps.io:8080/hello_world
```

How to change the public port from where the application is listening ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to change the public port that clients connect to in order to contact your app on Cloud Foundry. This is mostly not possible in a PaaS/hosted platform as the platform operators are the ones who decide which ports are open to the public internet.

Why do you need the application to be available on port 8080? Perhaps there is a way to resolve that issue.

For more details, your application is running inside of the Cloud Foundry runtime and is thus expected to listen on a port defined by that runtime. The recommended way to do this is to listen on the port specified in the `$PORT` environment variable.

For application manifests, I recommend looking over the documentation about what exactly is supported for these manifests: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html#optional-attributes.

Comment: Thanks. I will have to change the source code of the applications that access to it.

Answer (score 0):

You change it in Spring Boot's `application.properties` by this configuration:

```
server.port=9999
```

Take a look into this section of [Spring Boot reference docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-customizing-embedded-containers).

Obviously you need to change it also in Cloud Foundry manifest file.

Comment: My problem is the Cloud Foundry manifest file. It doesnt take in account the port parameter...